# Get the size of int array from parameter in C

Tags: c

I'm learning the C Language.

I need the size of the **int array**(passed in the parameter of a function).

I'm able to get the size of int array that using:

```
int size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(int);
```

But, When I'm using the same code on **parameterized** array, the above piece of code is not working for me.

Program:

```
void printArraySize(){
    int arr[]= {1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7};
    int size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(int);
    printf("\nSize = %d",size); // resulting right value
    doStuff(arr);
}
void doStuff(int arr[]){
    int size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(int); // resulting 1
    printf("\ndoStuff::Size = %d",size);
}
```

**Output:**

Size = 6
doStuff::Size = 1

The "size" value is displaying right. But, why **doStuff::Size** is 1 ?

Although, I'm using the same concept in both the functions the difference is only the parameterized array. 

Please give your suggestions or correct the mistake if I've done any.

Comment: It loses the size information when passed into a function. If you wrap the array in a struct then you can get the size in the function as well.

Comment: Have you searched for existing questions about this problem? I have doubts that you are the first person ever to encounter this.

Comment: I've encountered many questions. But, nothing was as similar what I observed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an array is passed to a function, it gets coverted into a pointer to its first element. So what you do inside your function is essentially equivalent to:

```
int size = sizeof(int*) / sizeof(int); // resulting 1
```

If you want to pass size, pass it as another argument to the function.

For example,

```
void doStuff(int arr[], size_t size){
..
}
```

and call the function as:

```
doStuff(arr, size);
```

You should really be using `size_t` for as `sizeof` operator returns a `size_t` which may be larger than an `int`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for such a quick response and much detail information. Presently, I'm working on this approach what you said. as @clcto said that "wrap the array in struct". I'll give it a try. Is there any other way apart from the directly passing the size as param?

Comment: No. The size information of array is lost in a function if you pass the array. So you have to pass in one way or other (another argument, global variable, as a member of the array itself -- e.g. 1st element or last element). Wrapping an array in a struct is one approach so that you can pass the struct by value.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs and observation. Got it.